# BoundaryDiscretizeRegion given an ImplicitRegion never returns

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, implicit

I am trying to generate random points on a "simple" 3D surface for testing purposes. The surface is a plane with etched or embossed rectangular structures.

I am using `ImplicitRegion` to model it :

```
GenerateCubes[y_, d_] := 
  MapThread[
   Cuboid[{#1, y, Min[0, #2]}, {#1 + 10, y + 10, Max[0, #2]}] &, 
   {Range[10, 100 - 1, 20], d*2^Range[5]}]

reg = ImplicitRegion[
     (RegionMember[Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {110, 90, 0.}], {x, y, z}] ||
      Or @@ (RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ GenerateCubes[10, 0.2]) ||    
      Or @@ (RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ GenerateCubes[30, 0.1])) &&
      And @@ (Not[RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}]] & /@ GenerateCubes[50, -0.1]) &&
      And @@ (Not[RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}]] & /@ GenerateCubes[70, -0.2]),
     {{x, 0, 110}, {y, 0, 90}, {z, -6.5, 6.5}}];
```

This is what the object looks like :

```
RegionPlot3D[reg, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {{0, 110}, {0, 90}, {-6.5, 6.5}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: the 3d object]

Now when I try to discretize it (in order to randomly sample points in the region), the notebook freezes:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg]
```

What's happening? Is the region too complicated to be discretized?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You're right, I copied an old code, sorry about the mistake ! I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The region is a union of cuboids, which in FEM-talk is a [`HexahedronElement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HexahedronElement.html).  We can just take all the coordinate boundaries, divide space into cuboids according to the coordinates, and select the ones whose mid point lies in the region defined by the OP's expression, which I store in `exp`.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

exp = (RegionMember[Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {110, 90, 0.}], {x, y, z}] ||
       Or @@ (RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ 
         GenerateCubes[10, 0.2]) || 
      Or @@ (RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ 
         GenerateCubes[30, 0.1])) && 
    And @@ (Not[RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}]] & /@ 
       GenerateCubes[50, -0.1]) && 
    And @@ (Not[RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}]] & /@ 
       GenerateCubes[70, -0.2]) // Rationalize;

coords = Union @@ 
     Cases[exp, a_ <= # <= b_ :> {a, b}, Infinity] & /@ {x, y, z};

cuboids = Tuples[#][[{1, 5, 7, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4}]] & /@
   Select[
    Tuples[Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ coords],
    exp /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> Mean /@ #] &
    ];
ecoords = Union @@ cuboids;
nf = Nearest[ecoords -> Automatic];
emesh = ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> ecoords,
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[Map[First@*nf, cuboids, {2}]]}
   ];

mr = MeshRegion[emesh];
RegionPlot3D@ mr
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One advantage to direct construction is that the edges of the region are sharp, exact, not approximated.

Comment: I must say, Michael, you have become quite a supporter of the FEM stuff; I like and apprechiate that ;-)

Comment: Thanks. A couple of reasons are good functionality and good documentation that supports learning it.  Also a few of your posts on the site have been helpful. :)

Comment: I was looking for a solution that would not involve statically designing the region, more like the original question or the solution proposed by bbgodfrey , but it seems to be impossible at the moment. It is especially important as some other objects I work with might not be so easy to generate using FEM. I don't care for approximate regions using DiscretizeRegion as long as I have a general solution independent of the objects I am using, but I don't think it is currently possible to discretize regions with creases (negative portions), am I right ?

Comment: @user1766172 If `exp` changes and the corresponding region is still the addition and subtraction of cuboids, then the above code should compute the corresponding mesh.  I don't see how it's any more static than your original code.  Now, if you wish to have other shapes, spheres, tetrahedra or rotated cuboids, then my code won't work on that.  I think the problem with discretizing is the same as the problem with `Simplify[exp]` or even just `LogicalExpand[exp]`.  The mix of many `&&`,  `||`, `<=` seems to cause a combinatorial explosion of cases.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes I was speaking of other shapes, especially spheres and ellipsoids. But you summed it up perfectly, at the end of the day the region will be implicitly represented by a combination of too many conditions. I think I'll have to go for a numeric scheme if I want a generic solution rather than an analytic one using discretization. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, mathematica does not seem to be able to discretize the region produced by this method as well ... Is it normal ?

Comment: @user1766172 Another reason you see me using FEM frequently is that I run into such issues with `*Region*` functions now and then, and I don't know why they don't work. FEM seems more reliable in its domain; the Region functions have a broader scope, which no doubt leads to complications. Now, (1) `mr` is already a discretized mesh region, so I'm not sure what `DiscretizeRegion` is trying/failing to do with it. (2) If you want tetrahedral elements, then this works for me: `MeshRegion@ToElementMesh[emesh, "MeshElementType" -> TetrahedronElement]` (http://i.stack.imgur.com/wahkt.png).

Answer (score 5):

`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` can handle a variant of your `ImplicitRegion` just fine.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
  (RegionMember[Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {110, 90, 0.}], {x, y, z}] || 
      Or @@ (RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ GenerateCubes[10, 0.2]) ||
      Or @@ (RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ GenerateCubes[30, 0.1])) || 
    Or @@ (RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ GenerateCubes[50, 0.3]) || 
    Or @@ (RegionMember[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ GenerateCubes[70, 0.4]), 
  {{x, 0, 110}, {y, 0, 90}, {z, -6.5, 6.5}}];
```

[image]

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg]
```

[image]

On the other hand, `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` for the code in the question runs a long time.  Evidently, `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` has difficulty coping with the subtractive ("etched") portion of the `ImplicitPlot`.  I shall consider whether a work-around exists.

By the way, use the option `MaxCellMeasure` to improve the resolution of the `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`

**Solution**

An alternative, more compact way to produce the plot in the question is

```
reg = BooleanRegion[Xor, Flatten[
  {Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {110, 90, 0.}], GenerateCubes[10, 0.2], 
  GenerateCubes[30, 0.1], GenerateCubes[50, -0.1], GenerateCubes[70, -0.2]}]];
```

A `RegionPlot3D` of this expression is, of course, identical to that in the question.  Since this plot is constructed from a surface mesh, we should be able to extract it.  In fact, `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` is designed for that purpose.  Unfortunately, it responds that it is "not implemented for" this mesh.  However, it is easy to construct a do-it-yourself equivalent.  With the plot set equal to `p`,

```
Quiet[Cases[p, GraphicsGroup[{z_}] -> z, Infinity] /. i_Integer -> p[[1, 1, i]]];
```

is a mesh representation of the surface.  It is not so pretty, because the zoning is not regular, but it is a reasonably accurate mesh.  Greater accuracy, if needed, can be obtained by increasing `PlotPoints` in the original plot.

```
Graphics3D[%]
```

[image]

**Better Solution**

Define the region with taller `Cuboid`s, simply to see better the final result.

```
r = BooleanRegion[Xor, Flatten[
    {Cuboid[{0, 0, -65}, {110, 90, 0}], GenerateCubes[10, 02], GenerateCubes[30, 01],
     GenerateCubes[50, -01], GenerateCubes[70, -02]}]];
```

Next, plot the `Mesh` only for this object.

```
p = RegionPlot3D[r, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {{0, 110}, {0, 90}, {-65, 65}}, 
    Mesh -> 33, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

I presume that only the top surface is desired.  If so, it is easy to delete the sides and bottom.

```
DeleteCases[p // Normal, ({_, _, -65.} | {0., _, _} | {_, 90., _} | {110., _, _} | 
    {_, 0., _}), Infinity];
```

Finally, convert this into a region.

```
Quiet@DiscretizeGraphics[%]
```

[image]

This seems like a fairly general approach.  (The specific numbers introduced into the third step are just the boundaries of the box.)  Increase `Mesh -> 33` to a larger value for greater resolution.

Comment: You're right, this version is discretized correctly. However, I definitely need to take into account the subtractive portions.Do you mean to say that if I wait long enough, it should also work with the original implicit region (with subtractive region) ?

Comment: Yes it works well for this exact object, but as I mentioned, I was looking for a more generic solution. BoundaryDiscretizeRegion was IMO the best way to achieve this generically, but it seems to only work for some specific cases... Is it normal behaviour, meaning that in future releases it might handle the original case much better ? Thanks

Comment: @user1766172  My final solution is, I believe, quite general.  Nonetheless, I wonder whether a mesh is even what you want.  Instead, you could obtain a `List` of `Polygon`s that make up a 3D plot of whatever you like, and distribute your random numbers first to `List` elements weighted by their `Area`s and then to positions within the selected `Polygon`s.

Comment: The solution is good too, I can only accept one of the answers though. I wanted to use a mesh -- in case the solution was generic enough -- since I was planning on using actual CAD objects imported as STL or PLY files. But it seems it won't be this easy if the objects are complex, as I won't be able to use any of the solutions proposed here generically for custom 3D objects.